# Produce new multi-column data frame from existing multi-column data frames with logic

Tags: r, dataframe, logic

I have 3 data frames each with multiple columns. All columns are numeric values, and I would like to produce a fourth with logic like

```
# this doesn't work when data frames have more than one column
d <- ifelse(A > 0, B, C)
```

However all the samples of `ifelse` I've seen produce only a single output column. I'd like to operate on all columns. How can I achieve this?

For example, given these data frames

```
pivot <- data.frame(a=c(-1, 1), b=c(1, 1))
low <- data.frame(a=c(2.2, 3.3), b=c(4.4, 5.5))
high  <- data.frame(a=c(10.1, 11.2), b=c(12.3, 14.4))
```

I'd like some expression like

```
result <- ifelse(pivot > 0, high, low)
```

to produce

```
data.frame(a=c(2.2, 11.2), b=c(12.3, 14.4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to `matrix` will solve the case

```
 as.data.frame(ifelse(pivot > 0, as.matrix(high), as.matrix(low)))
```

-output

```
    a    b
1  2.2 12.3
2 11.2 14.4
```

Comment: I was on the right track, but didn't quite have it; thank you!

Comment: @quickshiftin the reason is that `data.frame` is a `list` of columns where as `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes